# Kafka connect S3 source connector ignores keys

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following files in AWS S3 backed up by the Kafka connect sink connector:

```
test_yordan_kafka_connect+0+0000023000.json
test_yordan_kafka_connect+0+0000023000.keys.json
```

When restoring the topic with Kafka connect S3 source the key file is being ignored, I see the following debug message in the log:

```
DEBUG [source-s3|task-0] Removing test-bucket/topics/test_yordan_kafka_connect/partition=1/test_yordan_kafka_connect+1+0000000000.keys.json from common prefixes. (io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3Storage:333)
```

My source config looks like so:

```
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
"tasks.max":"1",
"s3.region":"eu-central-1",
"s3.bucket.name":"test-bucket",
"topics.dir":"test-bucket/topics",
"format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
"partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
"schema.compatibility":"NONE",
"confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "blockchain-kafka-kafka-0.blockchain-kafka-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092",
"transforms":"AddPrefix",
"transforms.AddPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.AddPrefix.regex":".*",
"transforms.AddPrefix.replacement":"$0_copy
```

What should I change so that the key is stored in Kafka along with the message.

Comment: I have the same issue with avro records, this feels strange the sink connector allows for keys and header wrapping when the source can't use them !

Answer (score 0):

I ignore how to make sure that `.keys.json` is taken into account to construct the Kafka keys when reading the data from S3.

One trick I used to achieve the same thing though is simply to rely on the `ValueToKey` SMT transformer: if the key value is also part of the value payload, then injecting it into the key is as simple as adding an instance of the `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey` transformer in the source connector config.

Here is the relevant doc:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/valuetokey.html

And here is a great blog post about that transformer (part of a series of 12 posts that are equally great)
https://rmoff.net/2020/12/09/twelve-days-of-smt-day-2-valuetokey-and-extractfield/

In my specific case, the built-in behavior of `ValueToKey` was not doing exactly what I wanted, so I ended up writing my own `CustomKeyToValue` transformer used by my sink connector to make sure the key was stored in S3, and then a `CustomValueToKey` on the source connector to rebuild things into Kafka.

Writing such custom transformers is actually pretty easy, it's essentially just 20 lines of code or so inside a single java file, that you can then package with the `kafka-connect-maven-plugin`. Here is for example the code of the built-in `ValueToKey` that can serve as inspiration:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/28f013708ffe8e48e46f408c7f570bf2cd5c54b2/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ValueToKey.java/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ValueToKey.java

We can apply the same principle to save/retrieve the Kafka headers as well.

Comment: Yes I did think about that too and then I realized that the fields required for the keys are in nested records which you can’t access with ´ValueToKey’ transformer. 
Another possibility is to store it in a temporary topic and use some ksqldb to create the key a forward the record to the right topic but all those solutions seem awfully complicated.

Comment: Yes, I admit creating custom transformers is adding complexity. OTOH, when using Kafka Connect in a project, I find that we quickly need to create such transformers anyway, in order to anonymize data or fix timezone issues or add ingestion meta-data or what have you => once this setup is there, creating some supplementary ones for handling the Kafka keys is not much more work and provides more control. Nested types can be traversed there a well.