# Kafka connect S3 source failing with read-only registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to read avro records stored in S3 in order to put them back in a kafka topic using the S3 source provided by confluent.
I already have the topics and the registry setup with the right schemas but when the connect S3 source tries to serialize the my records to the topics I get this error

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
> Error registering Avro schema:  ...   at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:121)
> at
> io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:143)
> at
> io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:84)
> ... 15 more Caused by:
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
> Subject com-row-count-value is in read-only mode; error code: 42205
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:495)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:486)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:459)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:214)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:276)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:252)
> at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:75)

it seems that the connect producer does not try to get the schema_id if it exists but tries to write it but my registry is readonly.
Anyone knows if this is an issue or there are some configuration I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure the correct schema for that subject is already registered by some other means, you can try to set `auto.register.schemas` to false in the serializer configuration.

See here for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#handling-differences-between-preregistered-and-client-derived-schemas

Comment: Thanks a lot Svend, this fixed my issue but I also needed to add `use.latest.version:=true`. I now have another issue about keys that are not created by the source but I ll create a new question.

Comment: well it seems that I am not the only one having this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686880/kafka-connect-s3-source-connector-ignores-keys

Comment: Oh, I did something just like that a few weeks ago, while designing a system to store all the topic content into S3, and read it back into another one. I'll post a comment in that question. Note that if you have in mind a disaster-recovery scenario, you need to back-up the schema registry, as opposed to reconstructing its content by declaring the schemas one by one, since that would in general not lead to the same schema id associated to the same schemas.